# local maximum principle for monotone schemes

Tags: numerical-methods, maximum-principle

Consider a monotone scheme
$$
u_{k}^{n+1}=G\left(u_{k-p-1}^{n}, \ldots, u_{k+q}^{n}\right)
$$
We have that if $u_{k} \leq v_{k}$ for all $k,$ then $G(u)_{k} \leq G(v)_{k}$ for all $k$. How can we show that this monotone scheme satisfies local maximum principle:
$$
\text {min}_{i \in \text {stencil around} k} u_{j} \leq G(u)_{j} \leq m a x_{i \in \text { stencil around } j} u_{i}
$$
where we take
$$
v_{i}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{\max _{k \in s t e n c i l \text { around } i} u_{k},} & {\text { if } k \in \text { stencil around } i} \\ {u_{i},} & {\text { otherwise }}\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: It is not at all clear to me how to interpret your notation. It would be advantageous for you to use standard notation.

Comment: @CarlChristian You are right, but that is how the problem was, but I think I understand it better now and can rewrite it in a more clear notation, shortly.